# Reassign values to a numpy array using another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have two numpy arrays: `arr1` and `arr2` (`arr1` is sorted, `arr2` does not have to be sorted).

```
arr1 = np.array([0, 3, 7, 9, 13])
arr2 = np.array([1, 2, 7, 8, 12, 14])
```

I want to change each element in `arr2` by the element in `arr1` that is the closest to it from below. So for example, `1` and `2` are greater than `0` but less than `3`, so they must be changed to `0`, `12` is between `9` and `13`, so it must be changed to `9`, etc.

Desired output:

```
array([0, 0, 7, 7, 9, 13])
```

I got this array using a for-loop:

```
arr3 = np.arange(len(arr2))

for i in range(len(arr1)):
    mask = arr2>=arr1[i] if i is len(arr1)-1 else (arr2>=arr1[i])&(arr2<arr1[i+1])
    arr3[mask] = arr1[i]

print(arr3)
```

I was wondering if there was a more numpythonic solution. Thank you.

Comment: Careful with using `&` operand instead `and`. You may not end up with the right result.

Comment: `arr1[np.searchsorted(arr1,arr2, 'right') - 1]` if min(arr1) <= min(arr2). I don't know what should happen to values in arr2 that are smaller than min(arr1).

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny `min(arr1) <= min(arr2)` is always true (in my case). So your solution is exactly what I was searching for. If you put it as a submission, I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `min(arr1) <= min(arr2)` is given you can combine [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) and fancy indexing to get the result you want. `searchsorted` returns the indices where to insert `arr2` elements to keep `arr1` sorted. Select those from `arr1`.

```
arr1[np.searchsorted(arr1,arr2, 'right') - 1]
```